# How to use selected Items in a list

Tags: list, list-form

I have an **Events** list here (use date filter for 9 Dec 2015 to get items)
http://www.sd72.bc.ca/school/timberline/Pages/Flex_Calendar.aspx

By hitting the leftmost column, I can get a blue tick mark indicating I've selected an item.

I want a button that adds items to a **Signup** list based on the selected **Events**:

```
List: **Signups**
Column: User
Column: Event
COlumn: ...etc
```

When the user click a button, I want the **Signups** list to add a new entry for each of the selected items.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get selected items by

```
var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
var oList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('list name'); // Put your list name here        
var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
```

And perform actions using this `selectedItems`

Comment: Thanks.  Where does this code go? In a Workflow? Sorry, Sharepoint noob here.

Comment: Add a javascript file to your page or paste the code in a script editor.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  When I try this code I get the error `Object doesn't support property or method 'get_web'`

Comment: `listId` is picking up the list though, the debugger shows `listId = "{695209AE-4D15-433B-8EAF-A8AE9679962E}"`

Comment: Solution works , but you need to get the context first: `var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();`